# System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Mono.Cecil.Pdb

Tags: xamarin, mono, pdb-files

The "XamlCTask" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Mono.Cecil.Pdb, Version=0.10.0.0, PublicKeyToken=50cebf1cceb9d05e' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
File name: 'Mono.Cecil.Pdb, Version=0.10.0.0, PublicKeyToken=50cebf1cceb9d05e' ---> System.ArgumentException: The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))

System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Mono.Cecil.Pdb

```
1>The "XamlCTask" task failed unexpectedly.
1>System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Mono.Cecil.Pdb, Version=0.10.0.0, PublicKeyToken=50cebf1cceb9d05e' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
1>File name: 'Mono.Cecil.Pdb, Version=0.10.0.0, PublicKeyToken=50cebf1cceb9d05e' ---> System.ArgumentException: The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
1>   at System.AppDomain.nApplyPolicy(AssemblyName an)
1>   at System.AppDomain.ApplyPolicy(String assemblyName)
1>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.VsAppDomainManager.MatchAssemblyName(AssemblyName reference, AssemblyName definition)
1>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.VsAppDomainManager.FindAssembly(String name, IEnumerable`1 probingPaths)
1>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.VsAppDomainManager.VsAssemblyResolver.CoreAssemblyResolveHandler(Object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
1>   at System.AppDomain.OnAssemblyResolveEvent(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String assemblyFullName)
1>   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
1>   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)
1>   at System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
1>   at System.Type.GetType(String typeName)
1>   at Mono.Cecil.Cil.SymbolProvider.GetSymbolType(SymbolKind kind, String fullname)
1>   at Mono.Cecil.Cil.SymbolProvider.GetReaderProvider(SymbolKind kind)
1>   at Mono.Cecil.Cil.DefaultSymbolReaderProvider.GetSymbolReader(ModuleDefinition module, String fileName)
1>   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleReader.ReadSymbols(ModuleDefinition module, ReaderParameters parameters)
1>   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleReader.CreateModule(Image image, ReaderParameters parameters)
1>   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(String fileName, ReaderParameters parameters)
1>   at Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(String fileName, ReaderParameters parameters)
1>   at Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlCTask.Execute(IList`1& thrownExceptions)
1>   at Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlTask.Execute()
1>   at Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.Execute()
1>   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
1>   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ohhhh I already disabled Mono Debugging for Visual Studio.

Tools > Extensions and Updates> Mono Debugging for Visual Studio enable and restart VS solved it.